# Getting "cannot use object of stdClass as an array" trying to write a Drupal module

Tags: php, drupal

I'm doing a test on a selection of a Drupal database (currently with a static value, as I haven't coded in pulling the value from a database yet), and I keep getting either cannot use object of stdClass as an array, if I use fetchAll(), and function must be a string if I use fetchAssoc.

What am I doing wrong here? It's obviously an issue with incorrect datatypes, but I'm not exactly sure why.

```
function multi_reg_get_id() {

$typevalue = 'reg_type_1';

    $result = db_select('registration', 'reg')
      ->fields('reg', array('entity_id'))
      ->condition('type', $typevalue, '=')
      ->groupBy('entity_id')
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();

      print_r($result);

  return $result;
}
    /**
    * Generate checkboxes for multiple registration form
    */
function multi_reg_checkbox() {
    $checkbox = array();
    $multi_reg_id = multi_reg_get_id();
      foreach ($multi_reg_id as $regid) {
      print_r($regid['entity_id']);
        $node = $node_load($regid['entity_id']);
        $title = $node->title;
        $checkbox[$title] = $regid;
            }
    return $checkbox;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because knowing that objects are accessed via `->` and arrays via `[]` is required basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$regid` is probably object so you should use it like this: `$regid->entity_id`

Comment: When I switch everything to $regid->entity_id, I get the following error:

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [entity_id] => 22 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [entity_id] => 23 ) ) 22

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /domain/sites/all/modules/multi_reg/multi_reg.module on line 118

Comment: You are using undefined variable as function name, `$node_load`. That's another problem.

Comment: Meant that to be a function. This is what you get from writing code at 2 am in the morning.

Thanks.